# Bad query in cursol in procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, cursor, procedure

I have a problem with curosr exactly with query : SELECT Crc32 FROM tableName. I want read all rows from Crc32 column and based on the first four characters find a table that has the same name as the four digits

Error:

```
0   12:58:57    call ShowNewUserComments("User66")  Error Code: 1146. Table 'comments.tableName' doesn't exist
```

Call Procedure:

```
call ShowNewUserComments("User66");
```

Code

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXiSTS ShowNewUserComments $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ShowNewUserComments`(tableName varchar(255)/*, Date TIMESTAMP*/)
BEGIN


             DECLARE recordNotFound INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
             DECLARE oneRow VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "";
             DECLARE getCrc32,i int (11);
             DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Crc32 FROM tableName;    
             DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET recordNotFound = 1; 
             OPEN myCursor;
            set i = 0;
             allRows: LOOP
                FETCH myCursor INTO oneRow;
                   set  i = i + 1;
                     IF recordNotFound THEN
                        LEAVE allRows;
                     END IF;

             END LOOP allRows;
             CLOSE myCursor;

END
```

Comment: error tells you that Table 'comments.tableName' doesn't exist so before calling this sp you need to create table `tableName` in your database `comments`.

Comment: YES I know about this but I declare tableName input value in procedure . Table example input parametr in procedure "User66" and User66 exist in database

Comment: I want use set @query = ("SELECT Crc32 FROM ", tableName);    but is doesnt work for cursor. Another solution use:  set tableNameUser = CONCAT("User",UserId);  and UserId its input parametr BUT I cant use "SET" before word DECLARE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly substitute table name from variable into query in MySQL, for that you need to use dynamic sql using `PREPARE` like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXiSTS ShowNewUserComments $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ShowNewUserComments`(tableName varchar(255)/*, Date TIMESTAMP*/)
BEGIN

     DECLARE recordNotFound INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE oneRow VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "";
     DECLARE getCrc32,i int (11);
     DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Crc32 FROM temp_table;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET recordNotFound = 1;


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;

    SET @query1 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE temp_table AS
                            SELECT Crc32
                            FROM ',tableName,' ');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


     OPEN myCursor;
     set i = 0;
     allRows: LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO oneRow;
           set  i = i + 1;
             IF recordNotFound THEN
                LEAVE allRows;
             END IF;

     END LOOP allRows;
     CLOSE myCursor;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
END
```

Comment: error with word DECLARE after DEALLOCATE PREPARE....
I want paste a error code but I dont now how

Comment: Ohh my mistake. All `DECLARE` statements has to be on top. Try updated answer.